# Is it possible to create lagged variable that refers to t - k business days in a time series data frame with business days only and some missing days?

Tags: r

I have a time series data frame(see reproducible data frame below) where I want to create new columns of lagged variable values at t-1 and t-2 business days. All observations are business days. The data table is arranged according to the first variable/column that specifies and is formatted as date according to '% Y-% m-% d'. The problem is that there are occasionally time gaps where one or more business days are missing in the data frame, which means that when I create lagging variables, it may cause incorrect lagging values in some cases that are based on previous observations when actually NA is to be specified because the t-1 or t-2  business  day is missing. Thus, my question is, is there any smart way to create lagged variables that avoid this problem?

Below I have provided an reproducible data frame as an example:

```
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame( date = as.Date(c("2019-06-24", "2019-06-25","2019-06-27", "2019-06-28","2019-07-01", "2019-07-03", "2019-07-04", "2019-07-08", "2019-07-09","2019-07-10")),
  X = sample(1:10),
  Y = sample(1:10),
  Z = sample(c("YES", "NO"), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

As you can observe, I have intentionally left out some business days. And, if you run following code that creates  lagged variables traditionally you can observe that the output will be inaccurate.

```
install.packages(data.table)
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)[, paste0('X', 1:2) := shift(X, 1:2)][]
setDT(Data)[, paste0('Y', 1:2) := shift(Y, 1:2)][]
setDT(Data)[, paste0('Z', 1:2) := shift(Z, 1:2)][]
```

E.g. on date 2019-06-27 the desired outputs for lagging variables “X1” and “X2” would be ‘NA’ since the date 2019-06-26 is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(data.table)

irregularShift <- function(date_var, val, k) sapply(date_var, function(x) val[date_var == x - k])

setDT(Data)[
  , paste0('X', 1:2) := list(irregularShift(date, X, 1), irregularShift(date, X, 2))][
    , paste0('Y', 1:2) := list(irregularShift(date, Y, 1), irregularShift(date, Y, 2))][
      , paste0('Z', 1:2) := list(irregularShift(date, Z, 1), irregularShift(date, Z, 2))
  ]
```

Output:

```
          date  X  Y   Z X1 X2 Y1 Y2  Z1  Z2
 1: 2019-06-24  9  3 YES                    
 2: 2019-06-25  4  1 YES  9     3    YES    
 3: 2019-06-27  7  5 YES     4     1     YES
 4: 2019-06-28  1  8  NO  7     5    YES    
 5: 2019-07-01  2  2 YES                    
 6: 2019-07-03  5  6 YES     2     2     YES
 7: 2019-07-04  3 10  NO  5     6    YES    
 8: 2019-07-08 10  9  NO                    
 9: 2019-07-09  6  4  NO 10     9     NO    
10: 2019-07-10  8  7 YES  6 10  4  9  NO  NO
```

Here though `X2` is not missing for `2019-06-27` as we're looking into `t-2` and `2019-06-25` is there. If this is undesired, you'll need to reformulate the shifts you'd like to see, perhaps with additional conditions.

Comment: Although the proposed solution solves the problem in cases where business days are missing, problems arise when we create rows for red days. In the latter cases, the lagged values ​​t-1 and t-2 on a Monday e.g. will incorrectly be NA according to the sunday and saturday values when they accurately should be based on existing values ​​of Friday and Thursday. The same issue would arise if e.g. you have one or more holidays in middle of week. E.g. if wednesday is a holiday the t-1 value ​​on thursday would incorrectly indicate NA instead of value of the t-1 business day value of tuesday.

Comment: Please enrich you data frame with such exceptions and indicate how they should be reflected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add the missing dates to your data so that the `shift` function works properly. Here I'm assuming "Business Day" means weekday, but obviously you could construct the vector any way you want. This requires that you know which days are business days in order to construct the vector, but that knowledge would be required of any approach.

```
bus_days <- 
  df[, {days <- seq(min(date), max(date), by = 'day')
        days[!format(days, '%u') %in% 6:7]}]

df[J(bus_days), on = 'date']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `library(bizdays)` where you can identify a date based on a difference number of business days using `offset(dates, n, cal)`:

```
library(bizdays)
Data1 <- Data %>% arrange(date) %>% mutate(lag_1_date = offset(date, -1), 
                                           lag_1_days = as.integer(date - lag_1_date), 
                                           X_1_value  = lag(X, k = lag_1_days),
                                           X_1_date   = lag(date, k = lag_1_days),
                                           X_1_final  = if_else(X_1_date == lag_1_date, X_1_value, NA_integer_),
                                           
                                           lag_2_date = offset(date, -2), 
                                           lag_2_days = as.integer(date - lag_2_date), 
                                           X_2_value  = lag(X, k = lag_2_days),
                                           X_2_date   = lag(date, k = lag_2_days),
                                           X_2_final  = if_else(X_2_date == lag_2_date, X_2_value, NA_integer_))
```

Note, the steps can be compressed and expanded to include `Y` and `Z` or other values at other lags.